# PHP: why msg_receive() receives wrong type?

Tags: php, ipc

I test msg queue in PHP with the following code.

```
<?php

$mq = msg_get_queue(3141592653589793238);

while (true)
{
    $msg_type = null;
    $msg = null;
    $max_msg_size = 32;

    msg_receive($mq, 1, $msg_type, $max_msg_size, $msg);
    print "receive: $msg ($msg_type)\n";
}

?>
```

According to the manual, if desired type (here, = 1) is positive, then the received type should be the same as desired type. But when I run the code, the output is like below. In addition, it is non-blocking and keeps receiving empty message when nothing is sent before.

```
receive:  (0)
receive:  (0)
receive:  (0)
receive:  (0)
receive:  (0)
receive:  (0)
receive:  (0)
receive:  (0)
receive:  (0)
receive:  (0)
receive:  (0)
```

So what is wrong here?

Comment: Maybe I use a key too long??? When I try a shorter one, it somehow works.

Comment: Nope, still not working.